# jenkins Emulator occasionally hangs indefinitely on startup

Tags: android, jenkins, amazon-ec2, android-emulator

**Problem:** when I try to build an android project on Jenkins, emulator occasionally hangs indefinitely on startup and the job finished: NOT_BUILT.

I have Jenkins slaves running on Debian EC2 instances - not using any emulator snapshots, every run is fresh with a clean workspace, so I haven't been able to figure out the difference as to why sometimes they are starting correctly and more often not.
In "Common emulator options", I checked the option: 'Reset emulator state at start-up'.

Jenkins version: 1.642
Android Emulator Plugin: 2.13.1

```
...    
    [android] Using Android SDK: /var/lib/jenkins/tools/android-sdk
    [android] Creating Android AVD: /var/lib/jenkins/.android/avd/hudson_it-IT_160_HVGA_android-22_armeabi-v7a.avd
    [android] /var/lib/jenkins/tools/android-sdk/tools/android create avd -f -a -s HVGA -n hudson_it-IT_160_HVGA_android-22_armeabi-v7a -t android-22 --abi armeabi-v7a
    $ /var/lib/jenkins/tools/android-sdk/platform-tools/adb start-server
    * daemon not running. starting it now on port 6345 *
    * daemon started successfully *
    $ /var/lib/jenkins/tools/android-sdk/platform-tools/adb start-server
    [android] Starting Android emulator
    $ /var/lib/jenkins/tools/android-sdk/tools/emulator -ports 6343,6344 -prop persist.sys.language=it -prop persist.sys.country=IT -avd hudson_it-IT_160_HVGA_android-22_armeabi-v7a -no-snapshot-load -no-snapshot-save -wipe-data -no-window
    resize2fs 1.42.13 (17-May-2015)
    The filesystem is already 140800 (4k) blocks long.  Nothing to do!

    emulator: WARNING: Increasing RAM size to 1GB
    Creating filesystem with parameters:
        Size: 576716800
        Block size: 4096
        Blocks per group: 32768
        Inodes per group: 7040
        Inode size: 256
        Journal blocks: 2200
        Label: 
        Blocks: 140800
        Block groups: 5
        Reserved block group size: 39
    Created filesystem with 11/35200 inodes and 4536/140800 blocks
    Creating filesystem with parameters:
        Size: 69206016
        Block size: 4096
        Blocks per group: 32768
        Inodes per group: 4224
        Inode size: 256
        Journal blocks: 1024
        Label: 
        Blocks: 16896
        Block groups: 1
        Reserved block group size: 7
    Created filesystem with 11/4224 inodes and 1302/16896 blocks
    emulator: warning: opening audio output failed

    emulator: UpdateChecker: skipped version check
    $ /var/lib/jenkins/tools/android-sdk/platform-tools/adb connect localhost:6344
    connected to localhost:6344
    [android] Waiting for emulator to finish booting...
    $ /var/lib/jenkins/tools/android-sdk/platform-tools/adb -s localhost:6344 shell getprop init.svc.bootanim
    error: device offline
    $ /var/lib/jenkins/tools/android-sdk/platform-tools/adb connect localhost:6344
    $ /var/lib/jenkins/tools/android-sdk/platform-tools/adb -s localhost:6344 shell getprop init.svc.bootanim
    error: device offline
    $ /var/lib/jenkins/tools/android-sdk/platform-tools/adb connect localhost:6344
    $ /var/lib/jenkins/tools/android-sdk/platform-tools/adb -s localhost:6344 shell getprop init.svc.bootanim
    error: device offline
    $ /var/lib/jenkins/tools/android-sdk/platform-tools/adb disconnect localhost:6344
    $ /var/lib/jenkins/tools/android-sdk/platform-tools/adb connect localhost:6344
    $ /var/lib/jenkins/tools/android-sdk/platform-tools/adb -s localhost:6344 shell getprop init.svc.bootanim
    error: device offline
    $ /var/lib/jenkins/tools/android-sdk/platform-tools/adb connect localhost:6344
    $ /var/lib/jenkins/tools/android-sdk/platform-tools/adb -s localhost:6344 shell getprop init.svc.bootanim
    error: device offline
    $ /var/lib/jenkins/tools/android-sdk/platform-tools/adb connect localhost:6344
    $ /var/lib/jenkins/tools/android-sdk/platform-tools/adb -s localhost:6344 shell getprop init.svc.bootanim
    error: device offline
    $ /var/lib/jenkins/tools/android-sdk/platform-tools/adb disconnect localhost:6344
    $ /var/lib/jenkins/tools/android-sdk/platform-tools/adb connect localhost:6344
    $ /var/lib/jenkins/tools/android-sdk/platform-tools/adb -s localhost:6344 shell getprop init.svc.bootanim
    error: device offline
    $ /var/lib/jenkins/tools/android-sdk/platform-tools/adb connect localhost:6344
    $ /var/lib/jenkins/tools/android-sdk/platform-tools/adb -s localhost:6344 shell getprop init.svc.bootanim
    error: device offline
    $ /var/lib/jenkins/tools/android-sdk/platform-tools/adb connect localhost:6344
    $ /var/lib/jenkins/tools/android-sdk/platform-tools/adb -s localhost:6344 shell getprop init.svc.bootanim
    error: device offline
    $ /var/lib/jenkins/tools/android-sdk/platform-tools/adb disconnect localhost:6344
    $ /var/lib/jenkins/tools/android-sdk/platform-tools/adb connect localhost:6344
    $ /var/lib/jenkins/tools/android-sdk/platform-tools/adb -s localhost:6344 shell getprop init.svc.bootanim
    error: device offline
    $ /var/lib/jenkins/tools/android-sdk/platform-tools/adb connect localhost:6344
    $ /var/lib/jenkins/tools/android-sdk/platform-tools/adb -s localhost:6344 shell getprop init.svc.bootanim
    error: device offline
    $ /var/lib/jenkins/tools/android-sdk/platform-tools/adb connect localhost:6344
    $ /var/lib/jenkins/tools/android-sdk/platform-tools/adb -s localhost:6344 shell getprop init.svc.bootanim
    error: device offline
    $ /var/lib/jenkins/tools/android-sdk/platform-tools/adb disconnect localhost:6344
    $ /var/lib/jenkins/tools/android-sdk/platform-tools/adb connect localhost:6344
    $ /var/lib/jenkins/tools/android-sdk/platform-tools/adb -s localhost:6344 shell getprop init.svc.bootanim
    error: device offline
    $ /var/lib/jenkins/tools/android-sdk/platform-tools/adb connect localhost:6344
    $ /var/lib/jenkins/tools/android-sdk/platform-tools/adb -s localhost:6344 shell getprop init.svc.bootanim
    error: device offline
    $ /var/lib/jenkins/tools/android-sdk/platform-tools/adb connect localhost:6344
    $ /var/lib/jenkins/tools/android-sdk/platform-tools/adb -s localhost:6344 shell getprop init.svc.bootanim
    error: device offline
    $ /var/lib/jenkins/tools/android-sdk/platform-tools/adb disconnect localhost:6344
    $ /var/lib/jenkins/tools/android-sdk/platform-tools/adb connect localhost:6344
    $ /var/lib/jenkins/tools/android-sdk/platform-tools/adb -s localhost:6344 shell getprop init.svc.bootanim
    error: device offline
    $ /var/lib/jenkins/tools/android-sdk/platform-tools/adb connect localhost:6344
    $ /var/lib/jenkins/tools/android-sdk/platform-tools/adb -s localhost:6344 shell getprop init.svc.bootanim
    error: device offline
    $ /var/lib/jenkins/tools/android-sdk/platform-tools/adb connect localhost:6344
    $ /var/lib/jenkins/tools/android-sdk/platform-tools/adb -s localhost:6344 shell getprop init.svc.bootanim
    error: device offline
    $ /var/lib/jenkins/tools/android-sdk/platform-tools/adb disconnect localhost:6344
    $ /var/lib/jenkins/tools/android-sdk/platform-tools/adb connect localhost:6344
    $ /var/lib/jenkins/tools/android-sdk/platform-tools/adb -s localhost:6344 shell getprop init.svc.bootanim
    error: device offline
    $ /var/lib/jenkins/tools/android-sdk/platform-tools/adb connect localhost:6344
    $ /var/lib/jenkins/tools/android-sdk/platform-tools/adb -s localhost:6344 shell getprop init.svc.bootanim
    error: device offline
    $ /var/lib/jenkins/tools/android-sdk/platform-tools/adb connect localhost:6344
    $ /var/lib/jenkins/tools/android-sdk/platform-tools/adb -s localhost:6344 shell getprop init.svc.bootanim
    error: device offline
    $ /var/lib/jenkins/tools/android-sdk/platform-tools/adb disconnect localhost:6344
    $ /var/lib/jenkins/tools/android-sdk/platform-tools/adb connect localhost:6344
    $ /var/lib/jenkins/tools/android-sdk/platform-tools/adb -s localhost:6344 shell getprop init.svc.bootanim
    error: device offline
    $ /var/lib/jenkins/tools/android-sdk/platform-tools/adb connect localhost:6344
    $ /var/lib/jenkins/tools/android-sdk/platform-tools/adb -s localhost:6344 shell getprop init.svc.bootanim
    error: device offline
    $ /var/lib/jenkins/tools/android-sdk/platform-tools/adb connect localhost:6344
    $ /var/lib/jenkins/tools/android-sdk/platform-tools/adb -s localhost:6344 shell getprop init.svc.bootanim
    error: device offline
    $ /var/lib/jenkins/tools/android-sdk/platform-tools/adb disconnect localhost:6344
    $ /var/lib/jenkins/tools/android-sdk/platform-tools/adb connect localhost:6344
    $ /var/lib/jenkins/tools/android-sdk/platform-tools/adb -s localhost:6344 shell getprop init.svc.bootanim
    error: device offline
    $ /var/lib/jenkins/tools/android-sdk/platform-tools/adb connect localhost:6344
    $ /var/lib/jenkins/tools/android-sdk/platform-tools/adb -s localhost:6344 shell getprop init.svc.bootanim
    error: device offline
    $ /var/lib/jenkins/tools/android-sdk/platform-tools/adb connect localhost:6344
    $ /var/lib/jenkins/tools/android-sdk/platform-tools/adb -s localhost:6344 shell getprop init.svc.bootanim
    error: device offline
    $ /var/lib/jenkins/tools/android-sdk/platform-tools/adb disconnect localhost:6344
    $ /var/lib/jenkins/tools/android-sdk/platform-tools/adb connect localhost:6344
    $ /var/lib/jenkins/tools/android-sdk/platform-tools/adb -s localhost:6344 shell getprop init.svc.bootanim
    error: device offline
    $ /var/lib/jenkins/tools/android-sdk/platform-tools/adb connect localhost:6344
    $ /var/lib/jenkins/tools/android-sdk/platform-tools/adb -s localhost:6344 shell getprop init.svc.bootanim
    error: device offline
    $ /var/lib/jenkins/tools/android-sdk/platform-tools/adb connect localhost:6344
    $ /var/lib/jenkins/tools/android-sdk/platform-tools/adb -s localhost:6344 shell getprop init.svc.bootanim
    error: device offline
    $ /var/lib/jenkins/tools/android-sdk/platform-tools/adb disconnect localhost:6344
    $ /var/lib/jenkins/tools/android-sdk/platform-tools/adb connect localhost:6344
    $ /var/lib/jenkins/tools/android-sdk/platform-tools/adb -s localhost:6344 shell getprop init.svc.bootanim
    error: device offline
    $ /var/lib/jenkins/tools/android-sdk/platform-tools/adb connect localhost:6344
    $ /var/lib/jenkins/tools/android-sdk/platform-tools/adb -s localhost:6344 shell getprop init.svc.bootanim
    error: device offline
    $ /var/lib/jenkins/tools/android-sdk/platform-tools/adb connect localhost:6344
    $ /var/lib/jenkins/tools/android-sdk/platform-tools/adb -s localhost:6344 shell getprop init.svc.bootanim
    error: device offline
    $ /var/lib/jenkins/tools/android-sdk/platform-tools/adb disconnect localhost:6344
    $ /var/lib/jenkins/tools/android-sdk/platform-tools/adb connect localhost:6344
    $ /var/lib/jenkins/tools/android-sdk/platform-tools/adb -s localhost:6344 shell getprop init.svc.bootanim
    error: device offline
    $ /var/lib/jenkins/tools/android-sdk/platform-tools/adb connect localhost:6344
    $ /var/lib/jenkins/tools/android-sdk/platform-tools/adb -s localhost:6344 shell getprop init.svc.bootanim
    error: device offline
    $ /var/lib/jenkins/tools/android-sdk/platform-tools/adb connect localhost:6344
    $ /var/lib/jenkins/tools/android-sdk/platform-tools/adb -s localhost:6344 shell getprop init.svc.bootanim
    error: device offline
    $ /var/lib/jenkins/tools/android-sdk/platform-tools/adb disconnect localhost:6344
    $ /var/lib/jenkins/tools/android-sdk/platform-tools/adb connect localhost:6344
    $ /var/lib/jenkins/tools/android-sdk/platform-tools/adb -s localhost:6344 shell getprop init.svc.bootanim
    error: device offline
    $ /var/lib/jenkins/tools/android-sdk/platform-tools/adb connect localhost:6344
    $ /var/lib/jenkins/tools/android-sdk/platform-tools/adb -s localhost:6344 shell getprop init.svc.bootanim
    error: device offline
    $ /var/lib/jenkins/tools/android-sdk/platform-tools/adb connect localhost:6344
    $ /var/lib/jenkins/tools/android-sdk/platform-tools/adb -s localhost:6344 shell getprop init.svc.bootanim
    error: device offline
    $ /var/lib/jenkins/tools/android-sdk/platform-tools/adb disconnect localhost:6344
    $ /var/lib/jenkins/tools/android-sdk/platform-tools/adb connect localhost:6344
    $ /var/lib/jenkins/tools/android-sdk/platform-tools/adb -s localhost:6344 shell getprop init.svc.bootanim
    error: device offline
    $ /var/lib/jenkins/tools/android-sdk/platform-tools/adb connect localhost:6344
    $ /var/lib/jenkins/tools/android-sdk/platform-tools/adb -s localhost:6344 shell getprop init.svc.bootanim
    error: device offline
    $ /var/lib/jenkins/tools/android-sdk/platform-tools/adb connect localhost:6344
    $ /var/lib/jenkins/tools/android-sdk/platform-tools/adb -s localhost:6344 shell getprop init.svc.bootanim
    error: device offline
    $ /var/lib/jenkins/tools/android-sdk/platform-tools/adb disconnect localhost:6344
    $ /var/lib/jenkins/tools/android-sdk/platform-tools/adb connect localhost:6344
    $ /var/lib/jenkins/tools/android-sdk/platform-tools/adb -s localhost:6344 shell getprop init.svc.bootanim
    error: device offline
    $ /var/lib/jenkins/tools/android-sdk/platform-tools/adb connect localhost:6344
    $ /var/lib/jenkins/tools/android-sdk/platform-tools/adb -s localhost:6344 shell getprop init.svc.bootanim
    error: device offline
    $ /var/lib/jenkins/tools/android-sdk/platform-tools/adb connect localhost:6344
    $ /var/lib/jenkins/tools/android-sdk/platform-tools/adb -s localhost:6344 shell getprop init.svc.bootanim
    error: device offline
    $ /var/lib/jenkins/tools/android-sdk/platform-tools/adb disconnect localhost:6344
    $ /var/lib/jenkins/tools/android-sdk/platform-tools/adb connect localhost:6344
    $ /var/lib/jenkins/tools/android-sdk/platform-tools/adb -s localhost:6344 shell getprop init.svc.bootanim
    error: device offline
    $ /var/lib/jenkins/tools/android-sdk/platform-tools/adb connect localhost:6344
    $ /var/lib/jenkins/tools/android-sdk/platform-tools/adb -s localhost:6344 shell getprop init.svc.bootanim
    error: device offline
    $ /var/lib/jenkins/tools/android-sdk/platform-tools/adb connect localhost:6344
    [android] Timed-out after waiting 720 seconds for emulator
    $ /var/lib/jenkins/tools/android-sdk/platform-tools/adb disconnect localhost:6344
    [android] Stopping Android emulator
    $ /var/lib/jenkins/tools/android-sdk/platform-tools/adb kill-server
    Finished: NOT_BUILT
```

Can Someone help me? Where and what is the problem?
Thank to all.